# How to use React redux hooks for updating state for just 1 value on click

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm fairly new to React Redux and am using it to display different transactions on a page. I have set up my store, then created my reducer & selector.

I have a filter state that is controlled by 3 buttons that when clicked, should change the type ('incoming', 'outgoing' or 'trades') and this renders different components based on this change.

Where I seem to be going wrong, is with updating the Redux value on click and ensuring the state also updates, I'm sure its an easy fix but haven't quite figured it out.

This is my reducer:

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const initialState = {
    filter_type: "outgoing",
}

const slice = createSlice({
    initialState,
    name: "transactionFilter",
    reducers: {
        setFilterType: (state, {payload}) => {
            state.filter_type = payload
        }
    }
})

const { reducer, actions } = slice;
export const { setFilterType } = actions;
export default reducer;
```

And my selector:

```
import {createSelector} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const baseState = (state) => state.transaction_filter;

export const transactionFilterSelector = createSelector(
    [baseState],
    (state) => state.filter_type
)
```

I'm importing the selector along with useDispatch/useSelector and can see the Redux state in my console.log, how can I use dispatch correctly to update everything?

This is my transaction file:

```
import React, {useMemo, useEffect, useState} from "react"
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";



const TransactionsPage = (props) => {

    const filterState = useSelector(transactionFilterSelector);

    console.log('Redux filter state: ', filterState);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState({
        type: filterState,
        sources: {
            type: "all",
            items: []
        },
        assets: [],
        dates: {
            type: "all",
            from: "",
            to: "",
        },
        category: "all",
    })

return (
      <div>
        <Heading level={'4'}>Choose a type</Heading>
        <div className={'tx-type-filter'}>
          {Object.values(TxTypes).map((i) => (
            <div
              className={`tx-type-item ${type === i ? 'selected' : ''}`}
              key={i}
              onClick={() => {
                  dispatch({type: setFilterType, payload: i});
                }}>
              <img src={image(i)} alt={'tx type'} />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
)

export default TransactionsPage;
```

Thank you in advance for any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do `dispatch(setFilterType(i));`. You don't write out action objects in modern Redux.

Comment: Thank you, I thought this too but this console.logs the updated Redux state but my actual filter state does not update, it just remains as the initialstate so not sure where it goes wrong

Comment: There is no reason for your `filter` variable to update when `filterState` updates as you have written it - it is initialized with the value you pass in as "initial state" once and will never change afterwards, unless you manually call `setFilter` with a new value. Is there any particular reason why you are using `useState` here at all?

Comment: I appreciate the explanation! Mainly as I created it previously and was just using localStorage to store the filter type, and am now just trying to implement Redux. I thought about calling the dispatch function as well as setFilter on click but that doesn't seem like it would make sense

Comment: But why do you have that local state here in the first place? That is derived data, not actual state from what you have shared here.

Comment: It's actually a work application I've been working on updating, so alot of the code such as filter state was already in, and I'd just added to it. But now when implementing redux, being fairly new to it I was unfamiliar with how best to update it

Comment: If you have all that data in Redux, maybe give https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data a read.
If part of it is in the component, assemble that data in your component, using `useMemo`, - and keep only the actual per-component data in `useState`, not the full object.